# Force VS Code to Syntax Highlight a part of a file differently

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My most current HTML/CSS/TS project is being done with HTML components. And, in that context, it's pretty common to use strings to set up the inner HTML of components. So we have stuff like this everywhere:

```js
this.innerHtml = `
  <p>Blah blah</p>
`
```

Since the syntax highlighter only sees a string, everything within it is typically green or whatever other color. But I wish there was a way of making it highlighted as HTML code. Is there a way? Is there maybe a VS Code Extension for it?

I imagine a VS Code Extension could work by putting a comment on the line before (or two) the HTML code, something like this:

```js
// extension:begin:html
this.innerHtml = ` 
  <p>Blah Blah</p>
`
// extension:end
```

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html

Comment: Nice one. I think I would admit it as answer if you would like. Although it would be much better to have an extension that identified a tag pattern inside a string and highlighted it as HTML automatically, specially given that, in this project, it's either going to be plain text or HTML, not any other programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) pointed out, the [es6-string-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html) mostly does what I wanted.

The only thing I would change is I would have HTML as some sort of default in the settings, since, in my project, that's the only thing I need.

Comment: THis breaks the rest of the file after the closing backtick.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand your comment.